# Point www subdomain to naked domain instead of bucket name

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, amazon-s3

I've got a domain name (example.com) which I've purchased through namecheap. The website is a just static site that I recently decided to switch over to S3. Following the instructions on the aws website I've:

- Created two buckets: example.com and www.example.com
- Configured the example.com bucket to be a static website and placed my files in it.
- Configured the www.example.com bucket to redirect to the example.com bucket
- Created a hosted zone for my domain
- Placed a type A alias for example.com in my hosted zone that points to my example.com bucket
- Placed a type A alias for www.example.com in my hosted zone that points to my www.example.com bucket
- Taken the nameservers from the NS record in my hosted zone and in namecheap set my domain to use them.

When I go to example.com it works just as expected. When I go to www.example.com it takes me to my website correctly but it shows www.example.com.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com as the domain. I haven't been able to figure out how to get it to point to www.example.com instead. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Configured the www.example.com bucket to redirect to the example.com
>   bucket*

You want the actual redirect url configured in S3 to be https://example.com, not the url of your example.com bucket. Just update that and you should be good to go.